# not able to login through root on xrdp

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp

I was not able to login through root user in xrdp from Windows 10. If I try to login through any other user, I can login but I am not able to login through root user.

Here is my `sesman.ini` config file:

```
;; See `man 5 sesman.ini` for details

[Globals]
ListenAddress=127.0.0.1
ListenPort=3350
EnableUserWindowManager=true
; Give in relative path to user's home directory
UserWindowManager=startwm.sh
; Give in full path or relative path to /etc/xrdp
DefaultWindowManager=startwm.sh
; Give in full path or relative path to /etc/xrdp
ReconnectScript=reconnectwm.sh

[Security]
AllowRootLogin=true
MaxLoginRetry=4
TerminalServerUsers=tsusers
TerminalServerAdmins=tsadmins
; When AlwaysGroupCheck=true access will be permitted
; if the group TerminalServerUsers is not defined.
AlwaysGroupCheck=false
; When RestrictOutboundClipboard=true clipboard from the
; server is not pushed to the client.
RestrictOutboundClipboard=false

[Sessions]
;; X11DisplayOffset - x11 display number offset
; Type: integer
; Default: 10
X11DisplayOffset=10

;; MaxSessions - maximum number of connections to an xrdp server
; Type: integer
; Default: 0
MaxSessions=50

;; KillDisconnected - kill disconnected sessions
; Type: boolean
; Default: false
; if 1, true, or yes, kill session after 60 seconds
KillDisconnected=false

;; DisconnectedTimeLimit - when to kill idle sessions
; Type: integer
; Default: 0
; if not zero, the seconds before a disconnected session is killed
; min 60 seconds
DisconnectedTimeLimit=0

;; IdleTimeLimit (specify in second) - wait before disconnect idle sessions
; Type: integer
; Default: 0
; Set to 0 to disable idle disconnection.
IdleTimeLimit=0

;; Policy - session allocation policy
; Type: enum [ "Default" | "UBD" | "UBI" | "UBC" | "UBDI" | "UBDC" ]
; Default: Xrdp:<User,BitPerPixel> and Xvnc:<User,BitPerPixel,DisplaySize>
; "UBD" session per <User,BitPerPixel,DisplaySize>
; "UBI" session per <User,BitPerPixel,IPAddr>
; "UBC" session per <User,BitPerPixel,Connection>
; "UBDI" session per <User,BitPerPixel,DisplaySize,IPAddr>
; "UBDC" session per <User,BitPerPixel,DisplaySize,Connection>
Policy=Default

[Logging]
LogFile=xrdp-sesman.log
LogLevel=DEBUG
EnableSyslog=1
SyslogLevel=DEBUG

;
; Session definitions - startup command-line parameters for each session type
;

[Xorg]
; Specify the path of non-suid Xorg executable. It might differ depending
; on your distribution and version. The typical path is shown as follows:
;
; Fedora 26 or later    :  param=/usr/libexec/Xorg
; Debian 9 or later     :  param=/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
; Ubuntu 16.04 or later :  param=/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
; Arch Linux            :  param=/usr/lib/xorg-server/Xorg
; CentOS 7              :  param=/usr/bin/Xorg or param=Xorg
;
param=/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
; Leave the rest paramaters as-is unless you understand what will happen.
param=-config
param=xrdp/xorg.conf
param=-noreset
param=-nolisten
param=tcp
param=-logfile
param=.xorgxrdp.%s.log

[Xvnc]
param=Xvnc
param=-bs
param=-nolisten
param=tcp
param=-localhost
param=-dpi
param=96

[Chansrv]
; drive redirection, defaults to xrdp_client if not set
FuseMountName=thinclient_drives
; this value allows only the user to acess their own mapped drives.
; Make this more permissive (e.g. 022) if required.
FileUmask=077

[SessionVariables]
PULSE_SCRIPT=/etc/xrdp/pulse/default.pa


----------------------------------------------------------------**below is my xrdp.ini config file**--------------------------------------------------------------

[Globals]
; xrdp.ini file version number
ini_version=1

; fork a new process for each incoming connection
fork=true

; ports to listen on, number alone means listen on all interfaces
; 0.0.0.0 or :: if ipv6 is configured
; space between multiple occurrences
;
; Examples:
;   port=3389
;   port=unix://./tmp/xrdp.socket
;   port=tcp://.:3389                           127.0.0.1:3389
;   port=tcp://:3389                            *:3389
;   port=tcp://<any ipv4 format addr>:3389      192.168.1.1:3389
;   port=tcp6://.:3389                          ::1:3389
;   port=tcp6://:3389                           *:3389
;   port=tcp6://{<any ipv6 format addr>}:3389   {FC00:0:0:0:0:0:0:1}:3389
;   port=vsock://<cid>:<port>
port=3389

; 'port' above should be connected to with vsock instead of tcp
; use this only with number alone in port above
; prefer use vsock://<cid>:<port> above
use_vsock=false

; regulate if the listening socket use socket option tcp_nodelay
; no buffering will be performed in the TCP stack
tcp_nodelay=true

; regulate if the listening socket use socket option keepalive
; if the network connection disappear without close messages the connection will be closed
tcp_keepalive=true

; set tcp send/recv buffer (for experts)
#tcp_send_buffer_bytes=32768
#tcp_recv_buffer_bytes=32768

; security layer can be 'tls', 'rdp' or 'negotiate'
; for client compatible layer
security_layer=negotiate

; minimum security level allowed for client for classic RDP encryption
; use tls_ciphers to configure TLS encryption
; can be 'none', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'fips'
crypt_level=none

; X.509 certificate and private key
; openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
; note this needs the user xrdp to be a member of the ssl-cert group, do with e.g.
;$ sudo adduser xrdp ssl-cert
certificate=
key_file=

; set SSL protocols
; can be comma separated list of 'SSLv3', 'TLSv1', 'TLSv1.1', 'TLSv1.2', 'TLSv1.3'
ssl_protocols=TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3
; set TLS cipher suites
#tls_ciphers=HIGH

; Section name to use for automatic login if the client sends username
; and password. If empty, the domain name sent by the client is used.
; If empty and no domain name is given, the first suitable section in
; this file will be used.
autorun=

allow_channels=true
allow_multimon=true
bitmap_cache=true
bitmap_compression=true
bulk_compression=true
#hidelogwindow=true
max_bpp=32
new_cursors=true
; fastpath - can be 'input', 'output', 'both', 'none'
use_fastpath=both
; when true, userid/password *must* be passed on cmd line
#require_credentials=true
; You can set the PAM error text in a gateway setup (MAX 256 chars)
#pamerrortxt=change your password according to policy at http://url

;
; colors used by windows in RGB format
;
blue=009cb5
grey=dedede
#black=000000
#dark_grey=808080
#blue=08246b
#dark_blue=08246b
#white=ffffff
#red=ff0000
#green=00ff00
#background=626c72

;
; configure login screen
;

; Login Screen Window Title
#ls_title=My Login Title

; top level window background color in RGB format
ls_top_window_bg_color=009cb5

; width and height of login screen
ls_width=350
ls_height=430

; login screen background color in RGB format
ls_bg_color=dedede

; optional background image filename (bmp format).
#ls_background_image=

; logo
; full path to bmp-file or file in shared folder
ls_logo_filename=
ls_logo_x_pos=55
ls_logo_y_pos=50

; for positioning labels such as username, password etc
ls_label_x_pos=30
ls_label_width=65

; for positioning text and combo boxes next to above labels
ls_input_x_pos=110
ls_input_width=210

; y pos for first label and combo box
ls_input_y_pos=220

; OK button
ls_btn_ok_x_pos=142
ls_btn_ok_y_pos=370
ls_btn_ok_width=85
ls_btn_ok_height=30

; Cancel button
ls_btn_cancel_x_pos=237
ls_btn_cancel_y_pos=370
ls_btn_cancel_width=85
ls_btn_cancel_height=30

[Logging]
LogFile=xrdp.log
LogLevel=DEBUG
EnableSyslog=true
SyslogLevel=DEBUG
; LogLevel and SysLogLevel could by any of: core, error, warning, info or debug

[Channels]
; Channel names not listed here will be blocked by XRDP.
; You can block any channel by setting its value to false.
; IMPORTANT! All channels are not supported in all use
; cases even if you set all values to true.
; You can override these settings on each session type
; These settings are only used if allow_channels=true
rdpdr=true
rdpsnd=true
drdynvc=true
cliprdr=true
rail=true
xrdpvr=true
tcutils=true

; for debugging xrdp, in section xrdp1, change port=-1 to this:
#port=/tmp/.xrdp/xrdp_display_10

; for debugging xrdp, add following line to section xrdp1
#chansrvport=/tmp/.xrdp/xrdp_chansrv_socket_7210


;
; Session types
;
 
; Some session types such as Xorg, X11rdp and Xvnc start a display server.
; Startup command-line parameters for the display server are configured
; in sesman.ini. See and configure also sesman.ini.
[Xorg]
name=Xorg
lib=libxup.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
code=20

[Xvnc]
name=Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
#xserverbpp=24
#delay_ms=2000

[vnc-any]
name=vnc-any
lib=libvnc.so
ip=ask
port=ask5900
username=na
password=ask
#pamusername=asksame
#pampassword=asksame
#pamsessionmng=127.0.0.1
#delay_ms=2000

[neutrinordp-any]
name=neutrinordp-any
lib=libxrdpneutrinordp.so
ip=ask
port=ask3389
username=ask
password=ask

; You can override the common channel settings for each session type
#channel.rdpdr=true
#channel.rdpsnd=true
#channel.drdynvc=true
#channel.cliprdr=true
#channel.rail=true
#channel.xrdpvr=true
```

Please let me know if anything is wrong in the config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hellmaster,

***Usual disclaimer - Please avoid using root account on your Ubuntu system.  You have other options to perform the same without putting at risk your machine....***

xRDP is working fine against Ubuntu 20.04 when using the root account.  Your configuration looks correct at xrdp level

Have you enabled the root account on your ubuntu system ? Can you login locally (no xrdp) on your ubuntu system as root and get access to the Ubuntu desktop.  If you are currently logged on with your root account locally on Ubuntu machine, logoff your root session and try to access the system via xRDP using your root account.  This should be working as we just tested this

How did you performed the installation of xRDP... manual installation ?  Have you performed some post configuration in order to ensure that user experience would be the best ?

You can automate the installation of xRDP script and the post configuration settings by using the xrdp-installer script which can be found [here](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=15733) as well as how to use it

Hope this help
Till next time
See ya